# Verification: have I worked this legendre symbol correctly

Tags: legendre-symbol

Compute $(\frac{92}{11}$).

Now $92^2 \equiv x^2\ mod(11) $ Now since there is no such x that satisfies this, so the legendre symbol is $-1$. Is this right?

Also, can somebody explain in a slightly more layman's language what the significance of quadratic residues are?

Comment: $92 \equiv 4 \bmod 11$

Comment: Why are you looking at quadratic residue here anyway?

Comment: @BillWallis ?? $(a \mid p) \equiv a^{(p-1)/2} \bmod p$ but it is also $1$ if $a \equiv x^2$, $-1$ otherwise [Legendre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol) therefore $92 \equiv 4 \equiv 2^2 \bmod 11$  is enough for answering

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Legendre formula 
$\left( a \over p \right)=a^{(p-1)/2} \pmod p $ to manually compute the value. $\bmod 11$ you have:
$$\left( 92 \over 11 \right)\equiv 92^5 \equiv 4^5 \equiv 4\times 16^2 \equiv
4\times 25 \equiv 100 \equiv 1$$
Therefor you value $-1$ is wrong.

Comment: How did you get this step? $4×16^2$≡4×25

Comment: $16\equiv 5 \pmod {11}$